# ItemDataBound doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, datalist

The ItemDataBound Event of my datalist wasn't called although I have

```
AutoEventWireup="true"
```

in the header of the aspx page **and** I call the `databind()` method in the `page_load` and this is the datalist in the aspx page :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dl_ItemDataBound">
```

this is the `page_load`:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
    if (Request.QueryString["id"] == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
    dl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your page_load code?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I've added it to the question